# Matplotlib plot function is not producing a sequential line

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, visualization

I am trying to produce a 2D plot using matplotlib's plot function, but the resulting plot is a bunch of lines connecting the points in an unexpected way (not sequentially from left to right).

**WHAT I TRIED:**

Example code:

```
plt.plot(x[4],y[4], linewidth = 0.5)
plt.scatter(x[4],y[4])
```

Where x[4] and y[4] are arrays of shape (30,1)

**The current outcome:**
[image: current output]

**WHAT I EXPECTED:**
[image: desired result]

Using the seaborn library I can generate what I want, however, I need it on matplotlib. Any suggestions?

Comment: You need to sort the data by the `x` column.  Probably want to put them both in one array, sort the array, then separate them.

Comment: Hi 1) Can you provide us with [minimum reproducible code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for your plot? 2) Is there a particular reason for your preference for matplotlib over seaborn?

Comment: Can you call `plt.show()` after `plt.plot(x[4],y[4], linewidth = 0.5)`. It will be helpful if you can put `x `and `y `sample data in question.